# How to implement json datatype to store price history

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have a "Products" table in MySQL (5.7.10) that contains many products.
I want to include into "Products" table a field called HistoricalPrices using JSON datatype.

For the example "Products" table includes the following:

```
ProductID
ProductName
ProductDesc
CreateDate
Price

HistoricalPrices (json) NEW
```

**HistoricalPrice** should include "CreateDate" and "Price" keys in json and so i can add multiple changes of price.

I prefer this method (instead of adding new row per price history) because i just need these prices for reporting.

What i am looking for is the MySQL Query for adding new price changes inside HistoricalPrice field (json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start by initilialising the *HistoricalPrices* column with empty JSON arrays. You can do that with [`json_array`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-array):

```
UPDATE Products
SET    HistoricalPrices = json_array()
WHERE  HistoricalPrices IS NULL;
```

You should do the same when inserting new products:

```
INSERT INTO Products (..., HistoricalPrices)
       VALUES (..., json_array());
```

For adding a price to *HistoricalPrices* in an existing record, you could use [`json_array_append`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-array-append).

For example, to append a historical price of 12.34 on 2016-05-01 for product ID  1, you would execute:

```
UPDATE Products 
SET    HistoricalPrices =
           json_array_append(HistoricalPrices, 
               '$', json_object('CreateDate', '2016-05-01', 'Price', 23.65)
           )
WHERE  ProductID = 1;
```

Multiple prices can be added in one go:

```
UPDATE Products 
SET    HistoricalPrices =
           json_array_append(HistoricalPrices, 
               '$', json_object('CreateDate', '2016-05-01', 'Price', 12.34),
               '$', json_object('CreateDate', '2016-05-22', 'Price', 12.50)
           )
WHERE  ProductID = 1;
```

The structure of the JSON value will be:

```
[
    {
        "CreateDate": "2016-05-01",
        "Price": 12.34
    },
    {
        "CreateDate": "2016-05-22",
        "Price": 12.50
    }
]
```

Comment: Would it be possible to search inside the json array HistoricalPrices for a specific productID. Like looking for specific prices in a date range ?

Comment: That really is a different question. Would you mind posting a new question about that (after having verified that this answer works for you)?

Comment: Related question: How to do JSON array search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38423045/searching-inside-json-array-in-mysql