# Searching inside JSON array in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have a table of Products that also contains JSON datatype with JSON array - json_array() field.

For the example "Products" table includes the following:

```
ProductID
ProductName
ProductDesc
CreateDate
Price
HistoricalPrices (json)
```

I am appending the data using the follow query syntax:

```
    UPDATE Products 
SET    HistoricalPrices =
           json_array_append(HistoricalPrices, 
               '$', json_object('CreateDate', '2016-05-01', 'Price', 23.65)
           )
WHERE  ProductID = 1;
```

Example of structure of the JSON array:

```
> [
>     {
>         "CreateDate": "2016-05-01",
>         "Price": 12.34
>     },
>     {
>         "CreateDate": "2016-05-22",
>         "Price": 12.50
>     } ]
```

Would it be possible to search inside the JSON array for a specific productID. Like looking for specific prices in a date range ?

Comment: If you want to do this for one record, then another language is more suitable for this, like PHP. If you want to search products based on a condition inside these JSON values, then you are on the wrong track. You should design your database with a separate Historical Prices table, or use a *document* database, like MongoDB, which are stronger on dealing with nested structures. What exactly is your case?

Comment: [MySQL JSON Search Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html) might help, since I don't have latest MySQL, I cant test it on JSON Array.

Comment: @trincot mysql 5.7 has json, for those brave souls that want it

Comment: @Drew, I know that. Not sure why you tell me that. ;-) My take is that languages connecting to MySql are more suitable for doing such things. The MySql JSON functions are quite unhandy, and with languages like PHP you can just decode the JSON and treat the content as native arrays and objects.

Comment: Because who knows based on your comment above

Comment: Just for testing i tried: JSON_EXTRACT(HistoricalPrices, '$.CreateDate') >NOW()   but it doesn't seem to work on multiple json_array() and always returns nothing

Comment: Still looking for a solve for this issue.